# Laravel 4 custom validation error message

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

so I was trying to add a custom validation rules like this:

```
public function validateDateAfterField($attribute, $value, $params)
{
  return strtotime($value) > strtotime($this->data[$params[0]]);
}
```

It takes the value and validate with another field in array of data being validate

I wanted it to produce an error message like this:

```
Event End Date must be a date after Event Start Date
```

Here is my custom validation message:

```
":attribute must be a date after :before"
```

I've added these custom validation attributes:

```
'attributes' => array(
        'event_start'=>'Event Start Date',
        'event_end' => 'Event End Date',
    )
```

But when I cannot access it in my custom validation class, I've tried something like this:

```
return str_ireplace(":before", $this->attributes[$parameters[0]], $message);
```

but got an error `Undefined property:CustomerValidator::attributes`

Anyone knows how to do this properly?

Edit:

Extended it in my global.php

```
Validator::extend('date_after_field', 'CustomValidator@DateAfterField');
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

Comment: Did you define a `Validator::extend` method on this validation?

Comment: Yes, I've defined it in my global.php, I'll add the code in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer after reading the documentation of the validator class.

By using `$this->getAttribute($parameters[0])`, I manage to get the custom attribute name.